# Need event for "mouseover with file" for HTML5 Fileupload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, hover

Im working on an new HTML5 upload script for jQuery and i must recognoze the event, when user 'hovers' the div "with a file!!".
I wan't to hightlight the div.

Comment: Before you embark on your journey, have you tried using a pre-made one? http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For file dragging in html5 browsers, you can use drag and drop events.
The two events you need are `dragenter` (triggered when you drag and the mouse arrives on the element) and `dragleave` (triggered when the mouse leaves the element on a drag).

See also: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html